# Function component on the same page in not picking in route (react-router-dom v6) of react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have created a route in my react project using the methods of ***react-router-dom*** version 6.2.1.

But when I tried to fetch one route of a functional component written on the same implementation component it is not working.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {Routes ,Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage from './pages/homepage/homepage.component';

const CarsPage= () => {
  <div>
    <h1>CARS PAGE</h1>
  </div>
}

function App() {
  return (
   <div>
     <Routes >
       <Route exact path='/' element={<HomePage />} />
       <Route exact path='/cars' element={<CarsPage/>} /> // This route is not working.
     </Routes>
   </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

### Issue

The hats route is not picking up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your forgot the `return` statement in CarsPage

Change it to:

```
const CarsPage= () => {
  return (
  <div>
    <h1>CARS PAGE</h1>
  </div>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the components in BrowserRouter.
See everything works here: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-leavitt-7tr1d?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the above implementation, the `CarsPage` component does not return anything. Refactor it to return your JSX like so.

```
const CarsPage = () => (
    <div>
      <h1>CARS PAGE</h1>
    </div>
);
```

Also, import `BrowserRouter` from `"react-router-dom"` and wrap the "react-router-dom" component `<Routes />` with `BrowserRouter` as seen in the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview) like so

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

...

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route exact path="/cars" element={<CarsPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```